# How to status from string list using c#

Tags: c#

I am working on an application where I have a list of statuses like **Submitted, Approved, and Rejected**. In my scenario when all the statutes are **Approved** then I have to return **Approved** but if there is a single record that is **Rejected** then will return **Rejected**. If there is a record with the status **Submitted** and the other two are **Approved** then return **Submitted**. I have implemented a simple check base logic but I need to make it better with best practices and more generic.

```cs
List<string> statuses = new List<string>() { "Approved", "Approved", "Approved" };
var res = statuses.Where(x => x == "Approved").ToList();
    
if (res.Count() == statuses.Count())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Approved");
}

if (res.Where(x => x == "Rejected").Count() > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rejected");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Submitted");
}
```

How can I achieve this and improve my logic?

Comment: Any should be helpful like in `bool notApproved = statuses.Any(x => x != "Approved");`

Comment: Sure you want your statuses as text and not as enum?

Comment: I want my status as string

Comment: Besides the correct anwers below, I would like to highlight that your code has a bug. In your list named res, there are only appoved items, asking the res list for rejected items will always return an empty list. That line should ask the statuses list instead.

Comment: @0lli.rocks yes that is correct but that also might be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have a *clear order*

```
Approved < Submitted < Rejected
```

and we want to find out a *maximum*:

- if we have at least one `Rejected` we return `Rejected`
- if we don't have `Rejected` but at least one `Submitted` then we return `Submitted`
- we return `Approved` if and only if *all* the items are `Approved`

This can be written as

```
var result = statuses.MaxBy(item => Array.IndexOf(
  new [] { "Approved", "Submitted", "Rejected" }, item));
```

Comment: How should I know if it contains Submitted and Rejected status

Comment: @Muhammad Kamran: if `statuses` contains `Rejected` then `Array.IndexOf` returns `2` (index of `"Rejected"`) for this `item == "Rejected"`; which is maximum and that's why we get `"Rejected"`

Comment: Yes I have debug it got it.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> statuses = new List<string>() { "Approved", "Approved", "Submitted" };

if (statuses.All(x => x == "Approved"))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Approved");
}
else
{
    if (statuses.Any(x => x == "Rejected"))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Rejected");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Submitted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify the logic like this:

Have a function to work out the status:

```
private static string GetStatus(List<string> statuses) 
{
        if (statuses.Any(x => x == "Rejected")) return "Rejected";
        if (statuses.All(x => x == "Approved")) return "Approved";
        return "Submitted";
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetStatus(statuses));
```

Comment: How about If I define an extra list which contain all the three statuses is there any way to compare for status check.

Comment: @MuhammadKamran sure you can do something like this, check if any in List 1 match any in List 2.: List1.Any(x => List2.Any(y => y == x));